# Creating AD random user and add to existing AD group using terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to create two test users and add them to the already existing Azure AD groups using terraform. I want the password for these two users must be randomly generated. And also, these users to be deleted when my resources get destroyed through terraform. This ensures every time I create the resources only these two users are created.

Answer (score 0):

**azuread_user** is the Terraform resource to Manage a user within Azure Active Directory.
[image]
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/user

This Resource it is part of the Terraform Azure Active Directory Provider https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs